# Custom colors in tailwind.config.js work in dev but break production react build

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a tailwind.config.js file that looks like this:

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html', './src/css/safelist.txt'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: ['animate-pulse', 'animate-spin', 'visually-hidden'],
      boxShadow: {
        DEFAULT: '0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)',
        md: '0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)',
        lg: '0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)',
        xl: '0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)',
      },
      colors: {
        gray: colors.blueGray,
        'light-blue': colors.sky,
        red: colors.rose,
        'navy-blue': '#273A72',
        'cobalt': '#1F6DA4',
        'light-blue':'#A6CEE3',
        'light-grey':'#E8E8E8',
        'bright-red': "#FF0000",
        'pastel-green': "#53BB78"
      },
      outline: {
        blue: '2px solid rgba(0, 112, 244, 0.5)',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        inter: ['Inter', 'sans-serif'],
        'Roboto': ['Roboto', 'sans-serif']
      },
      fontSize: {
        xs: ['0.75rem', { lineHeight: '1.5' }],
        sm: ['0.875rem', { lineHeight: '1.5715' }],
        base: ['1rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
        lg: ['1.125rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
        xl: ['1.25rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
        "2xl": ['1.5rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
      },
      screens: {
        xs: '480px',
      },
      borderWidth: {
        3: '3px',
      },
      minWidth: {
        36: '9rem',
        44: '11rem',
        56: '14rem',
        60: '15rem',
        72: '18rem',
        80: '20rem',
      },
      maxWidth: {
        '8xl': '88rem',
        '9xl': '96rem',
      },
      zIndex: {
        60: '60',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    // add custom variant for expanding sidebar
    plugin(({ addVariant, e }) => {
      addVariant('sidebar-expanded', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
        modifySelectors(({ className }) => `.sidebar-expanded .${e(`sidebar-expanded${separator}${className}`)}`);
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

When running in the node dev server, everything works fine. However, building with this file makes everything blank and raises a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

In the console.

When I change the tailwind config file to

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html', './src/css/safelist.txt'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: ['animate-pulse', 'animate-spin', 'visually-hidden'],
      boxShadow: {
        DEFAULT: '0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)',
        md: '0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)',
        lg: '0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)',
        xl: '0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)',
      },
      colors: {
        gray: colors.blueGray,
        'light-blue': colors.sky,
        red: colors.rose,
      },
      outline: {
        blue: '2px solid rgba(0, 112, 244, 0.5)',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        inter: ['Inter', 'sans-serif'],
        'Roboto': ['Roboto', 'sans-serif']
      },
      fontSize: {
        xs: ['0.75rem', { lineHeight: '1.5' }],
        sm: ['0.875rem', { lineHeight: '1.5715' }],
        base: ['1rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
        lg: ['1.125rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
        xl: ['1.25rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
        "2xl": ['1.5rem', { lineHeight: '1.5', letterSpacing: '-0.01em' }],
      },
      screens: {
        xs: '480px',
      },
      borderWidth: {
        3: '3px',
      },
      minWidth: {
        36: '9rem',
        44: '11rem',
        56: '14rem',
        60: '15rem',
        72: '18rem',
        80: '20rem',
      },
      maxWidth: {
        '8xl': '88rem',
        '9xl': '96rem',
      },
      zIndex: {
        60: '60',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    // add custom variant for expanding sidebar
    plugin(({ addVariant, e }) => {
      addVariant('sidebar-expanded', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
        modifySelectors(({ className }) => `.sidebar-expanded .${e(`sidebar-expanded${separator}${className}`)}`);
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

(everything is the same except the custom colors)

The custom colors obviously disappear, but everything suddenly works fine and the production build renders properly.

Is there any way to fix this (fix being defined as a working production build w/ the colors)?

Comment: Which version of Tailwind are you using?

Comment: It’s ^2.2.19 in the package.json

Comment: We use 3.0.13 though as far as I know

Comment: Is it possibly having issues with your double-quoted custom colors, e.g. ("#FF0000")?

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the double quotes to single quotes does not fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out after many hours of work

For some reason, having the line

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
```

and using the colors it provided caused problems in the production build of react.

I thus instead just explicitly defined all of the needed colors and removed that import (i.e. like this:

```
...
colors: {
   ...
   red: {
          100: '#fff5f5',
          200: '#fed7d7',
          300: '#feb2b2',
          400: '#fc8181',
          500: '#f56565',
          600: '#e53e3e',
          700: '#c53030',
          800: '#9b2c2c',
          900: '#742a2a'
        },
        gray: {
          100: '#f7fafc',
          200: '#edf2f7',
          300: '#e2e8f0',
          400: '#cbd5e0',
          500: '#a0aec0',
          600: '#718096',
          700: '#4a5568',
          800: '#2d3748',
          900: '#1a202c'
        },
        white: '#fff',
        black: '#000',
        'navy-blue': '#273A72',
        'cobalt': '#1F6DA4',
        'light-blue':'#A6CEE3',
        'light-grey':'#E8E8E8',
        'bright-red': "#FF0000",
        'pastel-green': "#53BB78"
}
...
```

And removed the line at the top. This removed all of the build errors.